# Calling the method of the parent Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a nested child component:

```
<template>
    <main>
        ...
        <feedback></feedback>
    </main>
</template>
```

In the main component, I have a method:

```
methods: {
    filledInput: function () {
        ...
    }
},
```

How to call this method in a child component `feedback`?

Comment: Emit an event from the child that is handled by the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you'd emit an event from the child and react to it on the parent as Roy mentioned in the comment.

In the child component:

```
this.$emit('filled', {filledWith: 'this'});
```

In the parent:

```
<feedback 
    @filled="data => filledInput(data)"
>
</feedback>
```

Comment: Thanks, but used vuex